# SQL Merge Statement Check Constraint Error

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following code table A has a check constraint on column `Denial`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table a
(
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL  ,
    [EntityID] int ,
    Denial nVarchar(20) 

    CONSTRAINT Chk_Denial CHECK (Denial IN ('Y', 'N')),
)
```

Merge statement

```
MERGE INTO Table a WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS tgt
USING (SELECT DISTINCT 
           JSON_VALUE(DocumentJSON, '$.EntityID') AS EntityID,
           JSON_VALUE(DocumentJSON, '$.Denial') AS Denial
       FROM Table1 bd
       INNER JOIN table2 bf ON bf.FileUID = bd.FileUID
       WHERE bf.Type = 'Payment') AS src ON tgt.[ID] = src.[ID]  

WHEN MATCHED 
))  THEN 
        UPDATE SET tgt.ID = src.ID,
                   tgt.EntityID = src.EntityID,
                   tgt.Denial = src.Denial,
            
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (ID, EntityID, Denial)
         VALUES (src.ID, src.EntityID, src.Denial)
    
THEN DELETE
```

I get this error when running my MERGE statement:

> Error Message Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure storproctest1, Line 40 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The MERGE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "Chk_Column". The conflict occurred in the database "Test", table "Table1", and column 'Denial'. The statement has been terminated.

This is due to the source files having **"Yes"** and **"No"** instead of **'Y'** and **'N'**. Hence, I'm getting the above error.

How can I use a Case statement in merge statement to handle the above Check constraints error? or Any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn `Yes` to `Y` and `No` to `N` *before* merging your data. That would belong to the `using` clause of the merge query:

```
USING (
    SELECT Distinct 
        JSON_VALUE(DocumentJSON, '$.EntityID') AS EntityID,
        CASE JSON_VALUE(DocumentJSON, '$.Denial') 
            WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN 'No'  THEN 'N'
            ELSE JSON_VALUE(DocumentJSON, '$.Denial')
        END AS Denial             
    FROM Table1 bd
    INNER JOIN table2 bf ON bf.FileUID = bd.FileUID
    WHERE bf.Type = 'Payment' 
) AS src
```

The `case` expression translates Y and N values, and leaves other values untouched. Since this applies to the source dataset, the whole rest of the query benefits (ie both the `update` and `insert` branches).

Comment: Thanks for your help,  Case statement has worked.